# Conditional probability with two dice

Tags: probability, conditional-probability, bayes-theorem

I am trying to solve a problem.
Two dice (1 and 2) are rolled. Let's define the following events
$$
A_{1} = \text{the result of dice 1 is even}\\
A_{2} = \text{the result of dice 2 is even} \\
A_{3} = \text{both dice give the same result} \\
$$
I need to compute $P(A_3 | A_1 \cap A_2)$ and $P(A_{1} \cup A_{2} \cup A_{3}^{c})$. My calculations are the following
$$
P(A_3 | A_1 \cap A_2) = \frac{P(A_3 \cap A_1 \cap A_2) }{ P(A_1 \cap A_2)} = \frac{3/36}{3^2/36} = 1/3
$$

\begin{align*}
P(A_{1} \cup A_{2} \cup A_{3}^{c}) & = 1 - P(A_1^c \cap A_2^c \cap A_3) \\
 & = 1 - P(A_3| A_2^c \cap A_1^c)P(A_2^c \cap A_1^c) \\
&= 1 - \frac{1}{3} \cdot \frac{3^2}{36} \\
& = \frac{11}{12}
\end{align*}
but I don't know if it's correct. Could someone corroborate or help me?

Comment: They look correct to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They are correct, if you are in doubt you can just write explicitly the events and you can compare them to the results.